# How to pass a ${BUIL_NUMBER} of one job to job inside job in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins pipeline.

I have a jobA and jobB inside jobA how to send the latest ${BUILD_NUMBER} of jobA to jobB

```
 stage('Run')
        {
            steps 
            { 
                dir ('/path') 
                {
                    build job: 'abc'; <How to send the ${BUILD_NUMBER} here>
                    build job: 'cde';
                    build job: 'rrr';
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it as follows:

```
build job: 'abc', 
    parameters: [
        string(name: 'build_number', value: String.valueOf(BUILD_NUMBER))
    ]
```

Comment: should i go ahead change in job abc configuration too ?

Comment: @Ashu123 Yes. You need to change it to accept the parameter

Comment: what do i add in job abc ? or how should i accept it ? i have a command in execute shell for job abc? should i pass 
/jenkins-regression_testing-$build_number/testing.pl in execute shell of job abc ?

Comment: You need to make the job as parameterized job.

Comment: @Ashu123 You need to make the job as parameterized job

Comment: i added parameter as string and 
build_number
and in the execute shell i added /jenkins-regression_testing-$build_number/testing.pl  but when i trigger the job it is still not taking the build number the path that is triggering is  /jenkins-regression_testing-/testing.pl and fails.

Comment: i am confused! i hardcoded a value and still not working

Comment: @Ashu123 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172870/discussion-between-sagar-and-ashu123).

Comment: @Ashu123 any issue due to which you removed your vote?

Comment: Missed click. I have marked the solution as Answer. Thank You Sagar. it resolved my issue

Comment: @Ashu123 Great! Enjoy coding :-)